# How to use combobox to open specific form in Ms Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

How can we open specific form based on what we click in the combo box? I tried using macro but it only can be used for 1 value of the combo box only (cannot assign specific form for all value of combo box)

Comment: Welcome on SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), then improve your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Goto to Combo box properties and select Macro builder
2. Using Macro you can define all conditions and respective actions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Santosh ! It really helped me