# How to make to click in button and open form releated in value in combox in Ms Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I open a form as shown here: [How to use combobox to open specific form in Ms Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51297019/how-to-use-combobox-to-open-specific-form-in-ms-access)

But I still have a problem. When I click the button, it opens two forms immediately. What I want to do, when the value in the combobox is 1, is to open only form 1, and when the value in the combobox is 2, open form 2.

Should I correct something in my macro? How do I do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show your code and the values of your combobox

Comment: I use macro openform, values of combobox are Color1, Color2, Color3

Comment: OpenForm Condition Where [Forms]![Test1]![txtTest]='Color1' and OpenForm Condition where [Forms]![Test2]![txtTest]='Color2'

Comment: Maybe I should add macro If, but I don't know how?

Comment: Why 2 forms if data source is the same for both? Use 1 form and apply filter, which is what the WHERE argument is intended for.

Comment: Could you write how and where I should apply filter? Sorry but I beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't like this macro builder.
Here's a proper way to do it with VBA.

Select your combobox and go in the events. In the **After Update** event, remove your macro code and add VBA code instead, using the option "Code Builder"

Your code should be this :

```
Private Sub ComboBoxColor_AfterUpdate()

    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Dim strForm As String

    Select Case ComboBoxColor.Value

        Case "Color1"
            strForm = "Form1"

        Case "Color2"
            strForm = "Form2"

        Case "Color3"
            strForm = "Form3"

        Case Else
            MsgBox "I don't know what to do with this combobox value"
            GoTo Exit_Sub
    End Select

    DoCmd.OpenForm strForm, acNormal

Exit_Sub:
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error " & Err.Number
    Resume Exit_Sub

End Sub
```

Adapt ComboBoxColor with the proper name, and Form1/Form2/Form3 with the names of your forms of course (and the Color1/Color2/color3 if needed)

Comment: It is my correct code, can you see, because always show message I don't know what to do with this combobox value Private Sub

Comment: because you have to adapt COlor1, COlor2, Color3 with the values defined in your combobox

Comment: Polecenie126_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Dim strForm As String

    Select Case txtTest.Value

        Case "Gloss"
            strForm = "Test1"

        Case "Coolant"
            strForm = "Test2"

        Case "Thickness"
            strForm = "Test1"

        Case Else
            MsgBox "I don't know what to do with this combobox value"
            GoTo Exit_Sub
    End Select

    DoCmd.OpenForm strForm, acNormal

Exit_Sub:
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error " & Err.Number
    Resume Exit_Sub

End Sub

Comment: No, I change this

Comment: in my combobox values are coolant, gloss and thickness. Sorry I make mistake :(

Comment: Where is mistake?